# Ubuntu 19.04: can't update because `libcupsfilters1` is not configured

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 19.04 (4.15.0-48-generic) from 18.04. Since then I can't upgrade, because `apt` cannot configure `libcupsfilters1`.

I tried:

- to remove and/or reinstall the package
- `apt-get install -f`
- run `autoclean`, `autoremove`
- tried to install with `dpkg`

nothing worked so far. Google search is not helping much, since it's not finding the package name somehow.

Edit: requested output of `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

```
dpkg: error processing package libcupsfilters1:amd64 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcupsfilters-dev:amd64:
 libcupsfilters-dev:amd64 depends on libcupsfilters1 (= 1.20.2-0ubuntu3.1); however:
  Package libcupsfilters1:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libcupsfilters-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libcupsfilters1:amd64
 libcupsfilters-dev:amd64
```

Comment: Ha! Thats strage, i tried `sudo apt remove libcupsfilters1` and `sudo apt install ..` which always failed. but your suggestion worked! thanks a lot! but did my attempt not work?

Comment: Um...how do i mark your comment as answer? Do not see any button for this XD

Comment: Added a fresh answer explaining the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the other errors talk about a package (libcupsfilters1) being *unconfigured*, let's configure it:

```
sudo dpkg --configure libcupsfilters1
```

In this case, that output gives us the answer:

```
dpkg: error processing package libcupsfilters1:amd64 (--configure):
package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
reinstall it before attempting configuration
```

It's easy to reinstall a package using apt:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall libcupsfilters1
```